# Occurrence Manipulation?

Tags: c++

I was going over an interesting problem that seems really simple to understand logically and it is, but I can't think of an approach for it.

**Example:**

> Array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]

So we traverse from the beginning to the end and find the first index spot where it's a duplicate and then do the absolute difference of it.

The elements that occur in the array are *1, 2, 3*.

**1** => Doesn't occur anywhere, so it's just 0.

**2** => Occur at index spot 2 and 5, so abs(2 (First) - 5 (Last)) = *3*

**3** => Occurrence at 3 and 4, so abs(3 - 4) = *1*

And then we just add them up: 0 + 1 + 3 => **4**

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Your question as it stands is a little broad for stack overflow and is more algorithmic than programming

Comment: How come 1 doesn't occur anywhere? It's there in index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd run over the array and build a map from the value to a pair of indexes (first occurrence and last occurrence). The first time a value if met, I'd create a pair where both values are the same index, and in any subsequent occurrence, update the last index.
Then, when the map is ready, I'd run over it and sum the differences between each element's first and last indexes:

```cpp
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2 };
int len = 5;

// Accumulate into the map
unordered_map<int, pair<int, int>> m;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    int val = arr[i];
    if (m.find(val) == m.end()) {
        m[val] = make_pair(i, i);
    } else {
        m[val].second = i;
    }
}

// Go over the map and accumulate the differences:
int sum = 0;
for (auto iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); ++iter) {
    sum += (iter->second.second - iter->second.first);
}

cout << "Total differences " << sum << endl;
```